# Обучение yolov4-tiny

Tags: нейронные-сети

У меня возникла проблема при обучении darknet yolov4-tiny. Я пытаюсь обучить нейросеть для распознования символов на автомобильном номере (я знаю что это наверное не лучшая идея) , и при обучении на одном символе все работает нормально, но при обучении даже на 2 разных символах точность распознования становится очень низкой. Я размечал изображения по одному символу на изображении, допустим если на изображении с номером есть символы 85205BH я размечал только 4 чтобы потом можно было разделить датасет на тренировочный и тестовый (по другому не смог придумать). Для примера разметил символы 0, 1 и W по несколько сотен изображений и после обучения получаю около 30 % точности.

Пример моего датасета
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Config файл

````
# Testing
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=24
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.00261
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 6000
policy=steps
steps=4800.0,5400.0
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=2
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers=-1
groups=2
group_id=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1,-2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -6,-1

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers=-1
groups=2
group_id=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1,-2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -6,-1

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers=-1
groups=2
group_id=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -1,-2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[route]
layers = -6,-1

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

##################################

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=24
activation=linear



[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=3
num=6
jitter=.3
scale_x_y = 1.05
cls_normalizer=1.0
iou_normalizer=0.07
iou_loss=ciou
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=0
nms_kind=greedynms
beta_nms=0.6

[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 23

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=24
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 1,2,3
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=3
num=6
jitter=.3
scale_x_y = 1.05
cls_normalizer=1.0
iou_normalizer=0.07
iou_loss=ciou
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=0
nms_kind=greedynms
beta_nms=0.6 ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы пытаетесь написать какую-то NN со знакомой архитектурой по типу U-NET или, как в вашем случае, YOLO, то стоит зайти на kaggle или любой другой знакомый ресурс и посмотреть, как другие люди решают данную проблему.

Блокнот на YOLOv5 к вашим услугам, но всё же постарайтесь не использовать архитектуру YOLO для таких вещей.
https://www.kaggle.com/rkuo2000/yolov5-alpr

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я пробовал использовать тессеракт, но так и не смог добиться хороших результатов и мне показалось использование Yolo привело бы к более лучшим результатам, при условии что скорость мне не нужна. Даже в обучающих роликах вроде https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0jg1Hj2GhU даже автор не смог добиться хороших результатов при обучении tesseract.

Comment: Если мой ответ вас устроил, то отметьте мой ответ.